# How to prove that $1-\frac{1}{t} \leq \ln{t} \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)$?

Tags: integration, inequality

The question asks to use $\int_1^t{\frac{1}{x} \,dx}$ for $t>1$ to deduce that $1-\frac{1}{t} \leq \ln{t} \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)$. I've tried using lower and upper rectangles but still can't get to the inequality required. Is there another way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please ignore the three close votes: it is just three people that say a question for someone with exactly one reputation point and decided to assert they are great by not even saying a word of what is wrong with your question (nothing is)

Comment: Are you familiar with convexity of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$A$ is the coordinate $(1,1)$ on the curve $y=1/x.\quad B\ $ is the point $\ (t, 1/t).$ And $DC$ is on the $x-$ axis.

Then the inequality in the question comes from:

Area( Rectangle $EBCD$ )  $<$ Area under the curve between $x=1$ and $x=t$ $<$ Area(trapezium $ABCD$).

Indeed, since $\ t>1,\ -1 < -\frac{1}{t},\ $ and $\ \frac{1}{t} < 1,\ $ and so we get:

$$(t-1) \frac{1}{t} \leq \int_1^t{\frac{1}{x} \,dx} = \ln(t) - 0 \leq \frac{1}{2} (t-1)\left( 1 - \frac{1}{t} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( t + \frac{1}{t} - 2 \right)$$

$$\overset{\left(\frac{1}{t} < 1\right)}{<} \frac{1}{2} \left( t + 1 - 2 \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( t - 1 \right)  \overset{\left(-1 < -\frac{1}{t}\right)}{<} \frac{1}{2} \left( t - \frac{1}{t} \right). $$

Answer (score 1):

The lower bound can be proved by using a lower rectangle with vertices $(1,0), (t, 0), (t, 1/t), (1, 1/t)$.

The upper bound can be proved by using a trapezoid with vertices $(1,0), (t, 0), (t, 1/t), (1, 1)$.

Comment: In what way you *use* a rectangle? Your answer reads like an answer that will only help people that already know it.

Comment: I assumed OP can understand it already from the way OP asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this method. For $x\in[1,t]$, $\frac1t\le\frac1x\le1$ and hence
$$ \frac{1-t}t\le\ln x=\int_1^1\frac1xdx\le t-1. $$